# Conditionally chaining promises inside and outside of a loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, control-flow

In the following code, when the condition within the loop is satisfied we can't really be sure in which order are both asyncFunction called.

```
siblings.forEach(function(sibling, index) {
  // This condition may only be satisfied once (only one sibling may have data-selected true)
  if (sibling.getAttribute('data-selected') == 'true') { 
        asyncFunction(sibling);     
  }
})

asyncFunction(element);
```

Since I know asyncFunction() returns a promise I could chain those to ensure the order:

```
asyncFunction(sibling).then(asyncFunction(element));
```

But how to do this taking the condition into account ?

I considered wrapping the loop in a promise that resolves when the condition is satisfied or after the loop ends, but it seems a tad convoluted.

```
// Untested
function checkSiblings(siblings) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        siblings.forEach(function(sibling, index) {
          if (sibling.getAttribute('data-selected') == 'true') { 
                resolve(asyncFunction(sibling));    
          }
        })
        resolve();
    })
}

checkSiblings(siblings).then(asyncFunction(element));
```

I am sure this has been addressed before, but I can't find the right search keyboards.

Thank you

Comment: The loop doesn't have anything to do with the async call so get the loop done before you involve the promise.  Also, `.forEach()` should be pretty much avoided these days because it has far, far less loop control than a plain `for` loop, especially when you want to abort the loop when you've found what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry @jfriend00 but I don't fully understand what you mean with "get the loop done before you involve the promise" could you please give an example ? thank you

Comment: Well, you're calling `resolve()` inside the loop and it only ever does anything to the promise just the first time you call it.  So, you're apparently resolving a promise on the first match in the loop and then continuing to run the rest of the loop.  So, the promise is not connected to when the loop is done.  I can't tell whether you don't need the loop to continue or not.  If you do, then the promise is not properly connected to when the loop is done.  If you don't need the loop to continue, then you're running a bunch of unnecessary code.  Either way, this is not an ideal design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only one of the siblings can meet the criteria, using `find` will simplify your code:

```js
const selected = [...siblings].find( elem => elem.getAttribute('data-selected') == 'true' );
```

Mark `checkSiblings` as `async` so it always returns a Promise, and have it return the `asyncFunction` Promise when appropriate:

```js
return selected ? asyncFunction(selected) : null;
```

Then you can chain them as before:

```js
checkSiblings(siblings).then(() => asyncFunction(element));
```

All together you’d have something like this:

```js
async function checkSiblings (siblings) {
  const selected = [...siblings].find( elem => elem.getAttribute('data-selected') == 'true' );
  return selected ? asyncFunction(selected) : null
}

checkSiblings(siblings).then(() => asyncFunction(element));
```

Comment: Thank you. Correct me if I am wrong, I believe find() can't be used on a nodelist (Siblings is a nodelist of html elements, I didn't specify this sorry) Or can it ?

Comment: Use `Array.from(siblings).find(...)` or with spread operator `[...siblings].find(...)`

Comment: Oh. Right. Sorry. I’ll update the answer with the spread as @emi correctly suggested.

Comment: May it be that find won't work in that context? I made a jsFiddle to test it: https://jsfiddle.net/plagasul/auLbrd9j/7/

Comment: You're calling `document.querySelector('li')` which returns either [a single element or null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector#return_value). If you're only getting one element there's no need to turn it into an array or call find on it. Perhaps you meant to call [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways. One of them is using `Array.reduce` to [resolve promises sequentially](https://css-tricks.com/why-using-reduce-to-sequentially-resolve-promises-works/):

```js
[...siblings].reduce(
  async (prev, sibling)) => {

    // Await initial/previous promise (discard results)
    await prev;

    // This condition may only be satisfied once
    // (only one sibling may have data-selected true)
    if (sibling.getAttribute('data-selected') == 'true') { 
      // Return the async function promise
      return asyncFunction(sibling);
    }

    // async functions always returns a promise.
    // No need to return anything

   // Initial promise autoresolved
}, Promise.resolve())

// Once all have been executed
.then( () => asyncFunction(element));
```